# Seeking simple Latin translation for motto "fire, flow, transcendence"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, motto

I am in a community of flow artists and fire performers.  I'm putting together a "coat of arms" of sorts for this community, and would like to include a motto in Latin.  The motto in English would be along the lines of "Fire, Flow, Transcendence."  How would I phrase this in Latin?

More info: "Fire" (the noun), as in burning flames, + "Flow" (noun or verb), the act of moving or adapting gracefully, as in a stream or river, but also with respect to the mental "flow state" found through deep concentration on an engaging task = "Transcendence" (noun), a higher state of consciousness.

Think along the lines of "finding transcendence by way of flowing with fire"

The motto could be a sentence, or a disjoint collection of words (perhaps separated by commas).  Either way.  Importantly, the translation needs to be reasonably short, ideally no more than a few words.

My research so far has provided me with the following which I think are close, but I'm not sure how much to trust Google Translate lol:

- "*Ignis, Fluxu, Transcendentiam*"
- "*Ignis ex Fluxu Transcendentiam*"

Thoughts?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site! That's a very complete question! Just the kind of translation question we'd like to be asked

Comment: Keep in mind that 1) there is probably no single word to convey all the meanings of English _flow_ at once and 2) I don't think _transcendentia_ means the same as its English cognate (it's what they call a _false friend_)

Comment: thanks!  yeah I'm not concerned about a *perfect* translation, just looking for something that's as close as possible to the meaning I'm aiming for.  if one definition or another of "flow" should be used, I would say that the verb form, i.e. the act of moving or adapting gracefully as in a stream or river, is the most likely to be translated correctly and is what we should shoot for.  as far as "transcendentiam" being a "false friend," perhaps?  what might work better to signify mental / consciousness elevation?  thanks!

Comment: perhaps also something like (again, using Google Translate as a base here), instead of "transcendentiam" to indicate transcendence, to use "spiritus elevandi" to indicate elevation of the spirit.

Comment: so maybe something like "ignis et fluxus, spiritus elevandi" ("fire and flow, to elevate the spirit") - ?

Comment: maybe "ignis et fluo, spiritus elevandi" ?  replacing "fluxus" (which GT indicates is an adjective) with "fluo" (apparently the verb form).  ?