# What is "transcendence"?

Tags: word-request

Suppose I wish to talk about transcendence: the state of surpassing normal limits, particularly limits of the human mind and body.

The obvious answer is something like *transcendentia*, from *trans* + *scendō* with a couple endings added on, but given how the concept of transcendence has evolved over time I worry that this is a false friend.

Comment: Does the era matter to you? I'd guess *transcendentia* is used in more recent Latin but not classical.

Comment: I think _transcendentia_ might be fine in Eccl Latin/ Related, unanswered question: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/seeking-simple-latin-translation-for-motto-fire-flow-transcendence (though I think it doesn't refer to the same meaning of transcendence)

Comment: clue: [this paper](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/transcendentals-medieval/) discusses about the origin of the related (but more specific) philosophical meaning, as in _the transcendentals_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although *transcendo* might suit your purpose, I found that it was often used metaphorically not in the sense that you're speaking but more in the sense of exceeding moral boundaries, so your suspicion that it may be a false friend might be correct. Here's an example of it in the moral sense:

> "Cupit regnum, et quidem scelerate cupit, qui transcendere festinat
>   ordinem aetatis, naturae, moris Macedonum, iuris gentium." (Titus
>   Livius, *Ab Urbe Condita*, 40.11.7)

With respect to transcending the limits of mind and body, the idea of *ecstasis* might be closer to what you're talking about, and there are a number of different ways to express that idea such as: "*a sensibus alienari*", "*in mentis excessum rapi*" or "*a seipso discedere*".

Here's some examples of usage of these ideas:

> "Ergo non oportet propter hoc alienari a corpore vel rapi." (Bernard
>   de Trilia, *Quaestiones disputatae de cognitione*)
>
> "Sed cum spiritalis visio, penitus alienato a sensibus corporis animo,
>   imaginibus corporalium detinetur, sive in somnis sive in ecstasi, si
>   nihil significant quae videntur, ipsius animae sunt imaginationes:
>   sicut etiam vigilantes et sani, et nulla alienatione moti, multorum
>   corporum quae non adsunt sensibus corporis, cogitatione imagines
>   versant." (Augustine, *De Genesis ad Litteram*, XII.12.26)